# Why it's not possible to manipulate the TWSR directly?

Tags: i2c, c, switch

I think I forgot the reason for this SFR manipulation in microcontrollers; like, checking the TWSR in twi.

The technique for checking the values of the TWSR is by masking it with another variable or a value.

So, why not checking the TWSR directly in; for example, switch function for checking the values of TWSR?

Like, `switch (TWSR)`

instead of

`uint8_t Status;
  Status = TWSR & 0xF8;
  switch(Status)`

Or, substitute it in any function; like, `Serial.println(TWSR);` or `digitalRead(TWSR);`. DO I have to mask it? If so then why?

Comment: `switch` is not a function; it doesn't provide a result. `switch` is nothing else than an `if-else` in disguise. You can't change what `switch` do, nor re-implement it in any other way. A switch statement allows a variable to be tested for equality against a list of values. Each value is called a case, and the variable being switched on is checked for each switch case.

Comment: bit 0 and bit 1 of the TWSR register specify the I2C clock speed, so they may differ depending on the speed you selected (`Wire.setClock()`)

Comment: What I mean is that why I have to mask TWSR instead of substitute it in any function parameter?

Comment: You mask it to ignore bits you don't care about.  In a switch, you'd have to list all of those as explicit cases which would be inefficient to express in  source code, even if a very optimizing compiler might figure out how to condense the actual tests to ignore the irrelevant bits.

Comment: OK, then why don't just check for TWSR values even with bit 0 and bit 1 included in the test, because they have ..... or wait. I'm sorry, it must be masked because these two bits may change between different I2C clock speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it's not possible to manipulate the TWSR directly?
>   i2c c switch

Because your premise is wrong: it is routinely done to manipulate twsr directly.

As to the use of masks, well, because sometimes you only care about certain bits but not others. So you mask away those that you don't want.

Just that simple.

Comment: OK, so all SFRs are accessible for direct manipulation. But this one is masked for unwanted bits. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The mask is a must, because bit 0 and bit 1 are I2C clock speed bits and they are changeable between different I2C clock speed configurations.